# How to create a treeview with radio buttons in the [grand]child nodes?

Tags: vb.net, treeview, radio-button

I am trying to create a treeview that looks something like the following:

**Parent**

|__**Child1**

|__ __ __ O **Grandchild1**

|__ __ __ O **Grandchild2**

|__**Child2**

|__ __ __ O **Grandchild3**

|__ __ __ O **Grandchild4**

I am using vb.net in Visual Studio 2008. Any insights as to how I can accomplish this will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have radio buttons in a TreeView, only checkboxes.

A solution would be to make the checkboxes behave like radio buttons:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck
    If e.Node.Checked Then
        If e.Node.Level = 2 Then
            For Each node As TreeNode In e.Node.Parent.Nodes
                If node IsNot e.Node Then
                    node.Checked = False
                End If
            Next
        Else
            e.Node.Checked = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The `e.Node.Level = 2` check makes sure only grandchild nodes behave like radio buttons.

Set the TreeView's `CheckBoxes` property to `True` to enable checkboxes.

This is an example of how to change text style of selected nodes and its parents:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_BeforeSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.BeforeSelect
    If TreeView1.SelectedNode IsNot Nothing Then
        MakeSelected(TreeView1.SelectedNode, False)
    End If
    MakeSelected(e.Node, True)
End Sub

Private Sub MakeSelected(ByVal node As TreeNode, ByVal selected As Boolean)
    Dim SelectedFont As New Font(TreeView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    node.NodeFont = IIf(selected, SelectedFont, TreeView1.Font)
    node.ForeColor = IIf(selected, Color.Blue, TreeView1.ForeColor)

    If node.Parent IsNot Nothing Then
        MakeSelected(node.Parent, selected)
    End If
End Sub
```

It recursively changes the text style of the selected node and its parents and sets it back to the TreeView's default style when the selection changes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Arjan. The reason I hadn't set the TreeView's CheckBoxes property to true in the first place was because I didn't want them to appear in the parent and child nodes (just the grandchildren). I also want to change the text colour of the selected node and the nodes that it decends from. For example, if Grandchild3 is selected, I would like to see its text in bold blue as well as that of Child2 and Parent.

Comment: Sadly, checkboxes can only be enabled and disabled for all nodes, but when you use my example, the checkboxes of the parent and child nodes cannot be checked.

Comment: I added an example of how to change text style of selected nodes and its parents.

Comment: Thanks again for all of the feedback Arjan. I ultimatley used Infragistics' UltraWinTree to accomplish what I set out to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public Sub getAFCategories(selectedId As String)
        Dim cn As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        cn = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnStr"))
        Try
            Dim MerchantSiteId As String = get_MerchantSiteID()
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT categoryId, Category, ParentId FROM tblCategories"
            cn.Open()
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            TrViewAfCategories.Nodes.Clear()
            Me.PopulateTreeView2(dt, 0, Nothing, dt, selectedId)
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

 Private Sub PopulateTreeView2(dtParent As DataTable, parentId As Integer, treeNode As TreeNode, dtMain As DataTable, selectedId As String)
        Dim redindex As Integer = 1
        For Each row As DataRow In dtParent.Rows
            Dim child As New TreeNode() With { _
             .Text = row("Category").ToString(), _
             .Value = row("AFCategoryId").ToString() _
            }
            If row("ParentId").ToString() = 0 Then
                TrViewAfCategories.Nodes.Add(child)
                redindex = parentId + redindex
                Dim dtChild As DataTable = Me.GetFilterData(dtMain, child.Value) 'Me.getData("SELECT AFCategoryId, Category, ParentId FROM tblAFFeedCategories WHERE ParentId = " + child.Value)
                PopulateTreeView2(dtChild, redindex, child, dtMain, selectedId)
            Else
                If parentId = 1 Then
                    child.ShowCheckBox = False
                    Dim dtChild As DataTable = Me.GetFilterData(dtMain, child.Value)
                    If dtChild.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        If (selectedId = child.Text) Then
                            child.Text = "<input type='radio' name='rdoC" + row("AFCategoryId").ToString() + "' value ='" + row("Category").ToString() + "'  checked='checked'/>" + child.Text
                        Else
                            child.Text = "<input type='radio' name='rdoC" + row("AFCategoryId").ToString() + "' value ='" + row("Category").ToString() + "' />" + child.Text
                        End If
                    End If
                    treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(child)
                    'Me.getData("SELECT AFCategoryId, Category, ParentId FROM tblAFFeedCategories WHERE ParentId = " + child.Value)
                    PopulateTreeView2(dtChild, parentId, child, dtMain, selectedId)
                End If
            End If

        Next
    End Sub
 Private Function GetFilterData(parentData As DataTable, filterValue As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim dvFilter As New DataView
        dvFilter = parentData.DefaultView
        dvFilter.RowFilter = Nothing
        dvFilter.RowFilter = "ParentId = " & filterValue
        dt = dvFilter.ToTable()
        Return dt
    End Function
```

Comment: Add a basic explanation and not just code in your answer.