# dynamically add child list-view items in radio-button-list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

There is this asp.net radio-button-list which have three list view items.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbFolderOptions" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                        RepeatLayout="Flow" Font-Size="Medium" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbFolderOptions_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Calendar" Value="0" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Tasks" Value="1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Contacts" Value="2" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

on click of any of the options, there should be a child list that should come that have fix options.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbSubFolder" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                        RepeatLayout="Flow" Font-Size="Medium" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbSubFolder_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Editor" Value="0" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Reviewer" Value="1" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

for example :

If you have selected "calendar" than a child list should come under "calendar" indented like below.

- Calendar

  - Editor
  - Reviewer
- Tasks
- Contacts

I am comfortable it doing with javascript/jquery/c# but not able to figure out how to ident it. Working code will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Update :

Check this:

[**How to create a treeview with radio buttons in the [grand]child nodes?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863651/how-to-create-a-treeview-with-radio-buttons-in-the-grandchild-nodes)

---

I think you are looking for [**TreeView Control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The TreeView Web server control is used to display hierarchical data, such as a table of contents or file directory, in a tree structure. It supports the following features:

- Automatic data binding, which allows the nodes of the control to be bound to hierarchical data, such as an XML document.
- Site navigation support through integration with the SiteMapDataSource control.
- Node text that can be displayed as either selectable text or hyperlinks.
- Customizable appearance through themes, user-defined images, and styles.
- Programmatic access to the TreeView object model, which allows you to dynamically create trees, populate nodes, set properties, and so on.
- Node population through client-side callbacks to the server (on supported browsers).
- The ability to display a check box next to each node.

Comment: no i want to give user a look of tree view but what i want is radio buttons appended as child of parent radio button.